# cmd-tab to chrome always opens the second Chrome window

Tags: macos, google-chrome, application-switcher

I'm new to macbook after being a linux user for years.

One thing i'm finding annoying is this: in Chrome, let's say I have two windows open, each with a few tabs.  (A regular window and an incognito window, say).

If I <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> away from chrome, then <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> back, it always opens the second window, regardless of which one I was on before.  It feels like it should stay on whichever window I was on before cmd-tabbing away.

Is there a way to deal with this?  An option in the Chrome settings perhaps?

I know that I can switch between chrome windows with <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> but i'd rather not have to keep doing this if possible.

Comment: Is any of… fullscreen, multiple displays or multiple Spaces involved in this? Does the same happen if you use Safari to mimic the same setup?

Comment: @Tetsujin my setup is that I use the mac closed, with an external monitor.  The display prefs are set to "Mirror display", and the res set to that of the monitor (rather than the native screen).  There's no multiple workspace stuff, but I do have the taskbar shown permanently at the bottom of the screen in case that's relevant.

Comment: @Tetsujin in Safari, it works how i'd want it to work, ie to open the most recently used window.

Comment: I'd be inclined to find Chrome's bug reporter, then. If it's app-specific, it could be something they do [intentionally or otherwise] that others don't.