# Can I fix macOS when most apps don't remember which window I had open?

Tags: macos, big-sur, window-manager

I'm using Big Sur, 11.5.1, on the ARM architecture.

Some apps seem to be able to remember which window was active, but most don't.  So, in Chrome for example (one of the ones that don't remember), if I tab away to a different app, then tab back, it always opens the last window in the list.  It should (I think) open the one that was active when I tabbed away.  This behaviour is the same whether I alt-tab or click on the app in the App list at the bottom of the screen.

At first I thought that this difference was down to native apps being able to do it, but Terminal is a native app and it can't remember.

Apps that remember the active window:

```
Safari
Finder
```

Apps which don't remember the active window:

```
Atom 
Chrome
Open Office
Terminal 
iTerm2
```

This is a really annoying and disruptive problem.  Has anyone else seen this and/or found a solution?

Comment: iTerm seems to behave for me

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431280/cmd-tab-to-chrome-always-opens-the-second-chrome-window

Comment: @Tetsujin it is, essentially, though at that time I thought it was unique to Chrome.  Now i've discovered it seems to apply to lots of apps.  Rather than go back and modify that earlier question I chose to put up a new one.  Genuinely sorry if that's a breach of protocol.

Comment: @mmmmmm my issue is with iTerm2

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too sometimes (Big Sur on Intel).
Rebooting makes the issue go away.

Comment: Rebooting doesn't fix it for me, but thanks for responding.